# Group structure on the strip

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, lie-groups

Let $X$ is a strip between two different parallel lines $a$ and $b$ on a plane ($a,b\subset X$) and $h(x)=\min\limits_{l\in \{a,b\}}\{d(x,l)\}$.
Let $(X,*)$ be a topological group with the following property:
$$h(xy)\leq \max\{h(x),h(y)  \}.$$
It is a locally compact, connected, simply connected, Hausdorff group. I think it might be a Lie group, but which one I don't know. This situation can be transferred to higher dimensions and there I am also interested in the next question.
Does such a group exist?

Comment: Do you have a specific definition for a group structure on $X$ or are you considering any group structure (provided it exists...)?

Comment: Does the statement "It is a [list of conditions] group" mean that you want additionally (to the condition on $h$) to impose these conditions, or that they follow from the condition on $h$?

Comment: @Qfwfq, I am considering the standard definition of a topological group, this is just a special case of interest to me.

Comment: @LSpice, I want additional relevant requirements.

Comment: Every Lie subgroup containing an open subset is a component, so in your case is the whole group. But strips symmetric around the middle of your strip are subgroups, containing open sets (I think). So this is not a Lie group.

Comment: @Ben McKay , I am satisfied with this answer, it is a pity that it almost does not simplify the question. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand well, $X$ would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (I assume you're considering an open strip, otherwise it's not homogeneous so it can't be a topological group). Do you have any explicit examples of such objects?

Comment: (Or, if the topology you're putting on $X$ is not the one inherited from the plane, could you specify how you define it?)

Comment: @Qfwfq, Yes, I am considering topology induced from the plane. I have not been able to construct a single satisfactory example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such group does not exist. To derive a contradiction, assume that the strip $X=\mathbb R\times(-1,1)$ admits a continuous group operation $X\times X\to X$, $(x,y)\mapsto xy$, such that $h(xy)\le\max\{h(x),h(y)\}$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Let $c$ be any point on the central line $L=\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ and $f:X\to X$ be the homeomorphism defined by $f(x)=x^{-1}c$. Observe that $xf(x)=xx^{-1}c=c\in L$ for every $x\in X$.

Since the line $L$ is nowhere dense in $X$, the set $L\cup f^{-1}[L]$ is nowhere dense in $X$ and hence we can choose an element $x\in X\setminus (L\cup f^{-1}[L])$. Then for the points $x\notin L$ and $y=f(x)=x^{-1}c\notin L$ we have
$$1=h(c)=h(xy)>\max\{h(x),h(x^{-1}c)\},$$
which contradicts the choice of $h$.

Comment: I guess here $a$ and $b$ are $\mathbb R \times \{1\}$ and $\mathbb R \times \{-1\}$?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I had in mind the strip $\mathbb R\times(-1,1)$.